# How to add cells within column in html table?

Tags: html, html-table

I have trouble finding the right way to add cells into columns: Here is what I want to do:

[image]

A fiddle you get from : http://jsfiddle.net/AKrB3/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table style="margin-top: 40px" width="600" height="358" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" align="center"  border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">fasfg1
                            </td>
                            <td  width="42"></td>
                             <td align="center">fasfg2
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this tabular data? If it is, then why not just use cells and `rowspan` to get this effect? If you're using a table for a website layout then I suggest you re-consider and use semantic markup.

Comment: @MoinZaman hi, thanks for your comment... i would never build websites this way ;-P no thats for html email and the buggy nature of all emailclients...

Comment: HTML tables are the way to go for pretty emails then. iMx's suggestion to use another table withing the first cell is definitely an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, with rowspan.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <table style="margin-top: 40px" width="600" height="358" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" align="center"  border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">fasfg1
                        </td>
                        <td  width="42" rowspan="3"></td>
                         <td align="center" rowspan="3">fasfg2
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>zroizj</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>zroizj</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that it may be really hard to maintain this code if you want to add more rows in the left column in the future. It may be preferable to use 2 different tables.

Answer (score 1):

I would make one more table inside the left row and add the rows to the new table

Answer (score 1):

This is not a really great way to do it, but if you do it in one table, then you need separate rows for each cell and one for the rest of the items.  To make the other side the same size, you must use rowspan.  When you add a column, you would need to update the rowspan by one and make a new  of the specific size you are inserting and remove it from the height specified by the last .

The better way to do this is by using separate tables for each band or a table inside a table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        </head>
        <body>
            <table style="margin-top: 40px" width="600" height="358" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" align="center"  border="1">
                            <tr style="height:10px">
                                <td align="center">fasfg1</td>
                                <td width="42" rowspan="4"></td>
                                <td align="center" rowspan="4">fasfg2
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="height:10px">
                                <td align="center" height="5%">fasfg1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="height:10px">
                                <td align="center" height="5%">fasfg1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="height:100px">
                                <td align="center">fasfg1</td>
                            </tr>    
                        </table>
        </body>
    </html>​
```